# how to remove all duplicate items from list including that item

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to remove duplicate elements from the list.

I have

```
list=[1,2,1,2,3,1,3,4]
```

and I want to **drop** repeated items. That is, if an item in the list comes two or more times then it is exclude from the list completely. The final list should look like this:

```
new_list=[4]
```

In this example 1, 2 and 3 occur at least two time and therefore all these elements are removed from the list

```
list=[1,2,1,2,3,1,3,4]
new_list = [i for i in set(list)] # wrong; how do I fix this?
print new_list
```

Please note this is different from `set(list)` because `set` keeps all items in the list.

Comment: with 2 lines of code, I can't see any here...

Comment: and duplicate suggestion is wrong...

Comment: Please take a look at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. StackOverflow users expect that a question show some effort - it is not a code writing service.

Comment: I already used sets, remove, unique but in all output look like new_list=[1,2,3,4] but it want only new_list=[4] and remove 1,2 and 3 from list.

Comment: @SethMMorton I agree with Julien that duplicate classification is incorrect. Please re-open this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,1,2,3,1,3,4]

from collections import Counter
[i[0] for i in Counter(a).items() if i[1] == 1]
```

An even simpler answer is:

```
[i for i in set(a) if a.count(i) == 1]
```

Comment: @RishabhJadia I edited my answer to include an even simpler solution than my original solution.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this is understandable for me and work fine..thnk u again.